# problemas al instalar weblogic 12c en windows 10

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

actualmente necesito instalar weblogic en mi windows 10. he descargado el instalador y lo ejecuto por medio del commando 
**java -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls.jar** cuando empieza la Ventana de instalacion llego hasta esta Ventana:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve en la imagen me muestra error de java.lang.NullPointerException la verdad no se que lo este causando, soy nuevo en java. Agradeceria a alguien que pudiera colaborarme de verdad necesito instalar este servidor.

Comment: ¿en que ruta de directorio tenias tu jar de instalación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo tenia el mismo problema, es por que en mis variables de entorno la variable "temp" apuntaba a una ruta del directorio de mi usuario de windows, y resulta que mi nombre de usuario tiene un espacio en blanco, así que reemplacé las variables de entorno de TEMP para que apuntaran a "C:/temp" y con eso solucioné el problema.

Para quien se encuentre con este mismo problema, después de solucionarlo tampoco van a poder iniciar el "IntegratedWeblogicServer", es por el mismo problema, si su nombre de usuario en Windows tiene un espacio en blanco es mejor crear otro usuario.